# WCF Concurrency?

Tags: c#, wcf, iis-7, concurrency

I have a WCF service deployed to IIS 7 and the client. I thought the service is configured to handle concurrency. When I tested with two client, it took double the amount of time. I have spent hours and not yet able to figure out where I missed it. Any help/suggestions would be appreciated. Service1.svc.cs looks like this:

```
[ServiceBehavior( ConcurrencyMode = ConcurrencyMode.Multiple, InstanceContextMode = InstanceContextMode.PerCall)]
[CallbackBehavior(UseSynchronizationContext=false)]
public class Service1 : IService1
{        
    public byte[] DownloadFile()
    {
        byte[] byt = File.ReadAllBytes(@"C:\Temp\TestFile.pdf");
        System.Threading.Thread.Sleep(1000);
        return byt;
     }
}
```

Configuration:

```
    <system.net>
    <connectionManagement>
      <add address="*" maxconnection="100"/>
    </connectionManagement>
  </system.net>
  <system.web>
    <compilation debug="true" targetFramework="4.0" />
    <processModel autoConfig="false" maxWorkerThreads="1400" maxIoThreads="1400" minWorkerThreads="2"/>
    <httpRuntime minFreeThreads="1000" minLocalRequestFreeThreads="1000"/>
  </system.web>
  <system.serviceModel>
    <bindings>
      <basicHttpBinding>
        <binding name="Service1Binding" maxBufferSize="2147483647" maxBufferPoolSize="2147483647"
          maxReceivedMessageSize="2147483647" transferMode="Streamed">
          <readerQuotas maxDepth="2147483647" maxArrayLength="2147483647" maxBytesPerRead="2147483647" />
        </binding>
      </basicHttpBinding>
    </bindings>
    <services>
      <service name="DocService.Service1">        
        <endpoint address="http://localhost/DocService/Service1.svc" binding="basicHttpBinding"
          bindingConfiguration="" name="Service1Binding" bindingName="Service1Binding"
          contract="DocService.IService1" />
        <endpoint address="http://localhost/DocService/mex" binding="mexHttpBinding"
          name="mexpoint" contract="IMetadataExchange" />
      </service>
    </services>    
    <behaviors>
      <serviceBehaviors>
        <behavior>          
          <serviceMetadata httpGetEnabled="true"/>          
          <serviceDebug includeExceptionDetailInFaults="false"/>
          <serviceThrottling maxConcurrentCalls="100" maxConcurrentInstances="100" maxConcurrentSessions="100"/>
        </behavior>
      </serviceBehaviors>
    </behaviors>
```

[image: Transfer TimeLine in Fiddler]

Comment: Hmm - this should work. Does it make a difference if you comment out the file I/O call?

Comment: Well, like you said, I made other calls that does not involve I/O and it worked. How can I make it work with I/O?

Comment: Might have something to do with ReadAllBytes keeping the file open for a short while. Does it make a difference if you pick different files on each call?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The requests are taking much longer than 1s sleep time and the read time of, say, 10mb file. They should complete in maybe 1.1-2s There is something fishy here.

Comment out the read and return a new byte[0]. Does it take 1.0s now? Do you have concurrency now?

Edit: What client are you using?

Edit 2: Responding to your comment, the file transfer is not limiting concurrency in some way. WCF does not care what you do inside your service method. It knows nothing about files. The problem is that your disk is too slow and that serializing 36mb is probably slow too! You server is just too slow! You can find out, if the disk or the serializing is the problem by replacing the IO with new byte[1024*1024*36].

Comment: The file size is 36 MB. That's why it is taking longer time. I am using the console client. But when I comment the I/O operation, it worked. How can I make the concurrency working with File transfer?

Comment: The files will be opened for reading. They will not block each other. The problem is that reading the same file twice might turn the sequential IO of both operations into random IO on the disk drive.

Comment: you are correct, I got better performance when I set thread sleep to 1 sec and worked on smaller file (9mb). Concurrency seems working. So, to deal with big files do I need to increase server disk size? Is there any alternative way to do this?

Comment: Measure how many bytes per second you get from your disk. If it is less than 30mb/s you definitely have a random(ized) IO problem. It will help to serialize access the the disk using a global lock (static object @lock = new object();). This will get you the sequential speed the disk is capable of.

Comment: I replaced with new byte[1024*1024*36] and got the same result, taking longer time. Which proves that it is not the serializing issue but the slow disk. Is there any online source or link that I can find more information about "access the the disk using a global lock"?